# Determine image height within Fancybox

Tags: jquery

I have single.php rendered within Fancybox. For the purpose of resizing an image within single.php I am obtaining the image height in javascript using:

var contentheight = jQuery('.postimage').height();

The first load of single.php within Fancybox successfully populates the "contentheight" variable and I am able to resize the image as per my needs. However, when I use Fancybox's left/right navigation buttons to navigate to next post, the "contentheight" variable never gets populated. Any ideas on what could be causing this erratic behavior?

Comment: Could you share a link to the where this is happening? Also, how are you triggering your js?

Comment: @JohannesPille I am working with a local install. I don't quite understand when you say: triggering your js. I have all js files loaded using wp_enqueue_script() in the header. I have a page template that has link to single.php with class defined for Fancybox. Clicking the link loads single.php in Fancybox. Both the page template and single.php call the header using <?php get_header(); ?> as normally done.

Comment: Triggering: If you just include a js function in a page nothing is going to happen at all. Something has to make that function run at a given time. I assume you're using either the javascript [`load event`](http://tinyurl.com/mxzyua) or the jQuery [`.ready() method`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). I am also assuming that either triggers correctly on the first load, but not when navigating to the next post's content. I am sure it's a trivial solution, but your question is (almost) impossible to answer as long as the behavior can not be observed anywhere and you're sharing just one line of code.

Comment: @JohannesPille Thx for the reply. Well after some digging around this appears to be caused because of the browser caching the image. I came up with a simple solution to retrieve the image height using PHP getimagesize() and printing it as the ID of the image. Later, in JS I used: var contentheight = jQuery('.fluidimage').attr('id'); to retrieve the height and perform the necessary action. Btw, initially I was calling the desired function within jQuery(document).ready(function(). Again, Thx for the help.

Comment: Good find and good for you that you figured it out! Did you know that you may [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) (and accept it also)? Will help others with the same question, make for one fewer unanswered question on the site and make you'll gain some rep as an aside.

Comment: @JohannesPille Thx for letting me know that I could answer my own question. I've done that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I came up with the solution to retrieve the image height using PHP getimagesize() and printing it as the ID of the image. Later, in JS I used: var contentheight = jQuery('.fluidimage').attr('id'); to retrieve the height and perform the necessary action.

Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php
$imageurl = $pathtoimage;
$image_size = getimagesize($imageurl);
$image_height = $image_size[1];
// For image width, use $image_width = $image_size[0];
?>

<img id="<?php echo $image_height; ?>" class="fluidimage" src="<?php echo $imageurl; ?>" />
```

Here's JS code to transfer the image height to JS variable, which you use in your own function within the JS:

```
var contentheight = jQuery('.fluidimage').attr('id');
```